# Add rows before pasting data in a new sheet (between specific cells)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with data and I want to copy its data to another sheet. That's simple, but the problem is, I have to copy that selection to a range between two cells that is set, so if I add another row with data in the first sheet then when the macro runs, the data will overwrite the cells below the limit. How do I make it that if I add a row in the first sheet, before the macro pastes the data in the other sheet another row or a number of rows will be created to avoid the limit below being overwritten? 
For example, if the number of rows between two cells is 5 and the range I need to paste is 7, then, prior to pasting the data, the macro creates two more rows.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference and add rows if required

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyInsert()

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Set rngSource = Selection ' range to copy from

    Const SHEET_TARGET = "Sheet2"
    Const RNG_TARGET = "C12:C16"

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rngTarget As Range, n As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets(SHEET_TARGET)
    Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Range(RNG_TARGET)

    ' insert new ones
    n = rngSource.Rows.Count - rngTarget.Rows.Count
    If n > 0 Then
        rngTarget.Rows("2:" & n + 1).EntireRow.Insert
    End If

    rngSource.Copy rngTarget.Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```